# How execute the select query within the variable and how to declare default in "type" in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

We are trying to convert oracle bulk collect in the line  EXECUTE W_SQL INTO IFSC_FETCH_OBJ;

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE W_SQL BULK COLLECT
     INTO IFSC_FETCH_OBJ;
```

I have created a type called ifsc_fetch and created a type object as ifsc_fetch_string.

Here I am assigning the ifsc_fetch_string into IFSC_FETCH_OBJ variable.
W_SQL variable holds a dynamic select query statement.

I want to execute the select query within the variable W_SQL into IFSC_FETCH_OBJ. But during this query execution I am getting the error as malformed array literal: "XYZ00098"

*Error: NOTICE:  malformed array literal: "XYZ00098"
SELECT 0
SELECT 0
SELECT 0*

XYZ00098 is the IFSC Code being passed

```
DECLARE

   TMP_RECORD   IFSC;
   W_SQL        VARCHAR(500);
   W_IFSC       VARCHAR(50);
   W_BANK_NAME  VARCHAR(50);
   W_BRN_NAME   VARCHAR(50);
   W_CITY_NAME  VARCHAR(50);
   W_STATE_NAME VARCHAR(50);
   W_SQL_DATA   VARCHAR(500);
   
   IFSC_FETCH_OBJ ifsc_fetch_string;

W_SQL := 'SELECT IFSRID_IFS_CODE, IFSRID_BRN_NAME|| '' - '' ||IFSRID_BRN_PLACE, IFSRID_BRN_ADDR1 FROM IFSRID
            WHERE 1=1';
           
IF TRIM(P_IFSC) IS NOT NULL THEN
W_SQL := W_SQL || ' AND IFSRID_IFS_CODE LIKE ''%' || W_IFSC || '%''';
  ELSE
 IF TRIM(P_BANK_NAME) IS NOT NULL THEN
W_SQL := W_SQL || ' AND IFSRID_BRN_NAME LIKE ''%' || W_BANK_NAME ||
'%''';
 END IF;
END IF;
 
BEGIN
   EXECUTE W_SQL INTO IFSC_FETCH_OBJ;
```

---

I have created like this type in PostgreSQL but getting error like
*ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
LINE 16:     BEN_TYPE                     varchar(10) DEFAULT 'MB',*
please help me to solve this issue.

```
CREATE TYPE benefid AS (
BENEFICIARY_ID               varchar(100),
    BENEFICIARY_NAME             varchar(150),
    BENEFICIARY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER   varchar(50),
    BENEFICIARY_ACCOUNT_TYPE     varchar(50),
    BEN_TYPE                     varchar(10) DEFAULT 'MB', 
);
```

Comment: The docs [Create Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) show that there is no `DEFAULT` for this form of `CREATE TYPE`. The `DEFAULT` would be assigned when the type was used in a table.

Comment: sir, if i want assign default value to type. How can i assign it. Is any way is there.

Comment: Read the docs at the link I posted. For a composite type like you are creating there is not a way to add a default.